# TFS 2015: TFS hosting path when using "server"

Tags: team-foundation-server

In TFS 2015 the "publish" task in a build definition may either push to the TFS server or to a fileshare/UNC path. Unfortunately, deleted builds aren't automatically pruned if you're using a fileshare. However, I'm unable to determine where TFS hosts the published builds when you're using the "server" option.

I do not have direct access to the TFS server, just the agent hosts. However, I have a sandbox environment whose local TFS admin doesn't appear to expose any configuration for where this path might be, either.

Does anyone have more information than I do? Where are these builds hosted in TFS? Where is this configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using target "Server" the data is stored inside the TFS Project Collection database. In the same table used for Version Control, Test data and Work Item Attachments. There is no further configuration possible.

"Server" drops will be purged from the database through the retention policy.

The files are not stored in a folder or on local disk of any of the TFS servers.

Comment: My understanding is that UNC paths are also purged of builds based on the retention policy.

Comment: They are in XAML they're currently not for the new task based builds.